# Permutation to get Stolarsky representation from lazy Fibonacci (dual Zeckendorf) representation

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations, recurrences

Let $a_1(n)$ be [A200714](https://oeis.org/A200714), i.e., Stolarsky representation interpreted as binary to decimal integers. The sequence begins with
$$0, 1, 3, 2, 7, 5, 6, 15, 4, 11, 13, 14, 31, 10, 9, 23, 12, 27, 29$$
Let $a_2(n)$ be [A358654](https://oeis.org/A358654), i.e., numbers whose binary expansion begins and ends with 1 and does not contain two adjacent zeros with rewrite $1\to 1$, $01\to 0$ applied to binary expansion. The sequence begins with
$$0, 1, 3, 2, 7, 5, 6, 15, 4, 11, 13, 14, 31, 9, 10, 23, 12, 27, 29$$
Both sequences given above are almost the same, aren't they? So there must be some nifty permutation for the case when we need to get one sequence from another.

Let $f(n)$ be [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045), i.e., Fibonacci numbers: $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. The sequence begins with
$$0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987$$

Let $g(n)$ be [A072649](https://oeis.org/A072649), i.e., $n$ occurs $f(n)$ times. The sequence begins with
$$1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7$$
Here we also consider that $g(0)=0$.

Now let's create some useful functions to define a permutation:
$$b(n)=f(g(n)+2)-n-1, b(0)=0$$
$$c(n)=f(g(n)+3)-n-1, c(0)=0$$
$$d(n)=c(b(n))$$
$$e(n)=f(g(n)+1)$$
$$h(n)=c(b(b(c(n))))$$
$$t(n)=n-e(n)-1$$
$$s(n)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if $t(n)<0$;}\\
g(t(n))\operatorname{mod}2,&\text{if $t(n)\geqslant 0$ and $g(n)\operatorname{mod}2=1$;}\\
1-g(t(n))\operatorname{mod}2,&\text{if $t(n)\geqslant 0$ and $g(n)\operatorname{mod}2=0$.}
\end{cases}$$
Let
$$a_3(n)=e(n) + [s(n) = 1]\cdot(f(g(n) - 2) + 1) - h(n) + a_3(h(n)) - 1 + \sum\limits_{k=e(n)}^{n} [s(k) = s(n)], a_3(0)=0$$
I conjecture that
$$a_2(n + a_3(d(n)) - d(n) - 1) = a_1(n)$$
Here is the PARI prog to verify this conjecture:

```
a1(n) = {if (n == 1, return (0)); tau = (1 + sqrt(5))/2; mn = 0; while ((m = round(mn*tau)) < n, mn++; ); if (m == n, return (2*a1(mn)+1)); mn = 0; while ((m = floor(mn*(1+tau)-tau/2)) < n, mn++; ); if (m == n, return (2*a1(mn))); error("neither A nor B !!"); }
Zeckendorf(n)=my(A=n, B, m=1, v=[1]); while(fibonacci(m+1)<=n, m++); m--; A-=fibonacci(m+1); while(m>1, m--; B=0; if(A-fibonacci(m+1)>=0, A-=fibonacci(m+1); B=1); v=concat(v, B)); v \\ A189920
g(n)=local(m); if(n<1, 0, m=0; until(fibonacci(m)>n, m++); m-2) \\ from A072649
a2(n)=if(n>0, my(A=concat(Zeckendorf(fibonacci(g(n)+3)-n-1), 0), B, x=3, v=[1]); while(x<=#A, B=0; if(A[x]==1, x++; B=1); v=concat(v, 1-A[x-B]); x++); fromdigits(v, 2)) \\ A247648 with rewrite 1 -> 1, 01 -> 0 applied to binary expansion
b(n)=if(n>0, my(A=g(n)); fibonacci(A+2) - n - 1)
c(n)=if(n>0, my(A=g(n)); fibonacci(A+3) - n - 1)
s(n)=my(A=g(n), n=n - fibonacci(A+1) - 1, B=g(n)%2); if(n>=0, if(A%2, B, 1-B))
a3(n)=if(n>0, my(A=g(n), B=fibonacci(A+1), C=s(n), D=c(b(b(c(n))))); B + if(C, fibonacci(A-2) + 1) - D + a3(D) - 1 + sum(k=B, n, s(k)==C))
a4(n)=my(A=c(b(n))); a2(n - A + a3(A) - 1)
test(n)=a4(n)==a1(n)
```

Is there a way to prove it? Is there a closed form or simper recurrence for the resulting permutation?

**UPD**: I have discovered another simpler recursion. Part of the functions are the same:
$$b(n)=f(g(n)+2)-n-1, b(0)=0$$
$$c(n)=f(g(n)+3)-n-1, c(0)=0$$
$$d(n)=c(b(n))$$
And then we define:
$$e(n)=n-f(g(n)+1)$$
$$h(n)=d(e(n))$$
$$s(n)=g(e(n)-1)$$
$$a_3(n)=n+[e(n)>0]\cdot(a_3(h(n)) - h(n) - f(s(n)) + [s(n)\operatorname{mod} 2 = g(n)\operatorname{mod} 2]\cdot f(g(n) - 2))$$
Here is the PARI code:

```
a3(n)=if(n>0, my(A=g(n), B=fibonacci(A+1), C=n-B, D=c(b(C)), E=g(C-1)); n + if(C>0, a3(D) - D - fibonacci(E) + if(E%2==A%2, fibonacci(A-2))))
```

Here we can also make a little change
$$a_3(n)=f(g(n)+1)+[e(n)>0]\cdot(e(n) + a_3(h(n)) - h(n) - f(s(n)) + [s(n)\operatorname{mod} 2 = g(n)\operatorname{mod} 2]\cdot f(g(n) - 2))$$
which shows that $a_3(n)$ use the resulting permutation $n + a_3(d(n)) - d(n)$ in the form of $e(n) + a_3(h(n)) - h(n)$.